# Composer - how to include test cases

Tags: composer-php

I want to use the following composer package "spatie/laravel-medialibrary" (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary)

How to include it with test cases? Neither require nor require-dev work for me:

```
"require": {
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^5.0"
},
```

or

```
"require-dev": {
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^5.0"
},
```

I just want to run the testcases included in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install this package from source - dist archive does not contain test nor documentation. Add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "source"
    }
}
```

And then remove this package from `vendor` directory and install again:

```
rm -rf vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/
composer install
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: One question - and how do I get the tests to autoloader?